# Could not autowire dao, No qualifying bean of type [...] found for dependency

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit, dao, autowired

I am currently developing a small application data access, which is Hibernate 4 as orm, and spring for the dependencies management. 
I am now at the dao layer, I want to test the insertion of a new entity in the database, but the problem I've had is at the injection interface "studentDao" in the test class.

This is my entity (Student)

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "student")
    public class Student{

        private Long studentId;
        private String cin;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private Integer age;
        private String phone;
        private String mail;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID", unique= true, nullable = false)
        public Long getStudentId() {
            return studentId;
        }

        public void setStudentId(Long studentId) {
            this.studentId = studentId;
        }

        @Column(name = "CIN", unique= true, nullable = false, length = 8)
        public String getCin() {
            return cin;
        }

        public void setCin(String cin) {
            this.cin = cin;
        }
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

this is the generic dao interface

```
public interface BaseDao<T, PK extends Serializable> {

    PK create(T entity);

    T getById(PK id);

    List<T> getAll();

    void createOrUpdate(T entity);

    void update(T entity);

    void delete(T entity);

}
```

and his implementaion

```
public abstract class BaseDaoImpl<T, PK extends Serializable> implements BaseDao<T, PK> {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Class<T> type;

    public BaseDaoImpl(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T getById(PK id) {
        return (id != null) ? (T) this.currentSession().get(this.type, id) : null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> getAll() {
        return currentSession().createCriteria(type).list();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public PK create(T entity) {
        if (entity != null) {
            return (PK) currentSession().save(entity);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void createOrUpdate(T o) {
        if(o != null){
                currentSession().merge(o);
        }
    }

    public void update(final T entity) {
        if (entity != null) {
            currentSession().merge(entity);
        }
    }

    public void delete(final T entity) {
        if (entity != null) {
            currentSession().delete(entity);
        }
    }

    protected Session currentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

student dao interface & class

```
public interface StudentDao extends BaseDao<Student, Long> {

}

@Repository("studentDao")
@Transactional
public class StudentDaoImpl extends BaseDaoImpl<Student, Long> implements StudentDao {

    public StudentDaoImpl(Class<Student> type) {
        super(Student.class);
    }

}
```

spring configuration file (applicationContext.xml), it is in: src/main/resources

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.souhaieb.education.cursus" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"></tx:annotation-driven>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <task:annotation-driven></task:annotation-driven>
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:persistence-mysql.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.pass}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.souhaieb.education.cursus.entities.Student</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

Finally, I wanted to test the insertion of a new student in the database, and for that I created the class MainTest to do

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(value = {"file*:applicationContext.xml"})
public class MainTest{

    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    StudentDao studentDao;

    @Test
    public void testStudent(){
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setCin("05454445");
        student.setFirstName("student1");
        student.setLastName("student1");
        student.setAge(27);
        studentDao.create(student);
    }

}
```

when running, here is the log

```
15:15:45.092 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.GenericApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@12029d31: startup date [Wed Aug 13 15:15:45 GMT+01:00 2014]; root of context hierarchy
15:15:45.162 [main] ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@3d7820f] to prepare test instance [com.souhaieb.education.cursus.MainTest@399ba8c1]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.souhaieb.education.cursus.MainTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.souhaieb.education.cursus.dao.StudentDao com.souhaieb.education.cursus.MainTest.studentDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.souhaieb.education.cursus.dao.StudentDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.mockito.InjectMocks(), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:384) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:331) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:213) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:292) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.souhaieb.education.cursus.dao.StudentDao com.souhaieb.education.cursus.MainTest.studentDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.souhaieb.education.cursus.dao.StudentDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.mockito.InjectMocks(), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.souhaieb.education.cursus.dao.StudentDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.mockito.InjectMocks(), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
15:15:45.167 [Thread-0] INFO  o.s.c.s.GenericApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@12029d31: startup date [Wed Aug 13 15:15:45 GMT+01:00 2014]; root of context hierarchy
```

Changing '@ContextConfiguration(value = {"file*:applicationContext"})' to '@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext"})'  full stack trace of the error is:

```
16:32:40.117 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext]
16:32:40.125 [main] ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@65c95a57] to prepare test instance [com.souhaieb.education.cursus.MainTest@64a39f6]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:331) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:213) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:292) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:253) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:122) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172) ~[spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Comment: try to add <context:component-scan base-package="com.souhaieb.education.cursus.dao" />

Comment: I did it, but always the same result

Comment: always same exception
I also fix an error in applicationContext.xml (<property name=annotatedClasses> to <property name="annotatedClasses">) and always same exception...

Comment: Why you use "file*:applicationContext.xml" instead "classpath:applicationContext.xml" for @ContextConfiguration? i'm not sure that is the same thing. I use it in this way @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:META-INF/applicationContext.xml"})

Comment: You have something weird in your configuration: two `transactionManager` bean definitions.

Comment: whene I use "classpath:applicationContext.xml" instead "file*:applicationContext.xml" the result is : failed to load ApplicationContext !

Comment: What happens if you remove `@InjectMocks` annotation and keep only `@Autowired`?

Comment: I removed it , nothing has changed

Comment: Show us the full stack trace of the error you get when you use `classpath:applicationContext`.

Comment: I believe your app doesn't actually use the .xml file you posted. I think there would have been an error about the same id - `transactionManager` - being used for two bean definitions. Also, if `src/main/resources` is on the build path then you shouldn't have any issues using `classpath:applicationContext.xml`.

Comment: I agree with @AndreiStefan. Your config file simply isn't found. And it isn't loaded.

Comment: @AndreiStefan is there a solution for getting the right path of xml file ?

Comment: I just changed to @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/applicationContext.xml"}) --> a new exception is triggered :
... Configuration problem: Bean name 'transactionManager' is already used in this <beans> element
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]...

Comment: That's the correct exception you should have gotten in the first place. This means that now you are using the correct .xml file.

Comment: Delete the first transactionManager bean definition (the one that uses LocalSessionFactoryBean).

Comment: @AndreiStefan This exception (transactionManager) is fixed, but the other exception occurred :
...Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': Instantiation of bean failed...
...Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Around...

Comment: @SSouhaieb try adding below dependencies

`<!-- AspectJ -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: @SSouhaieb NoClassDefFoundError should be easy. Usually, a library is missing and this exception is generated. As it was suggested above, add that dependency (if using Maven) and try again.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I'm really grateful.
I added the dependencies but the exception is always triggered, so I removed it because I did not need, and voila the new exception:
Error creating bean with name 'studentDao' defined in file [...\cursus\dao\impl\StudentDaoImpl.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.souhaieb.education.cursus.dao.impl.StudentDaoImpl]: No default constructor found; ...com.souhaieb.education.cursus.dao.impl.StudentDaoImpl.<init>()

Comment: Remove the argument from the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the constructor from BaseDaoImpl and I add the setter of the attribute "type".
In the StudentDaoIml, I override the default constuctor where I initialized into the type (Student.class).

BaseDaoImpl.java:

```
public abstract class BaseDaoImpl<T, PK extends Serializable> implements BaseDao<T, PK> {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Class<T> type;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T getById(PK id) {
        return (id != null) ? (T) this.currentSession().get(this.type, id) : null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> getAll() {
        return currentSession().createCriteria(type).list();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public PK create(T entity) {
        if (entity != null) {
            return (PK) currentSession().save(entity);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void createOrUpdate(T o) {
        if(o != null){
                currentSession().merge(o);
        }
    }

    public void update(final T entity) {
        if (entity != null) {
            currentSession().merge(entity);
        }
    }

    public void delete(final T entity) {
        if (entity != null) {
            currentSession().delete(entity);
        }
    }

    public void setType(final Class<T> typeToSet) {
        type = typeToSet;
    }

    protected Session currentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

StudentDaoImlp.java:

```
@Repository("studentDao")
@Transactional
public class StudentDaoImpl extends BaseDaoImpl<Student, Long> implements StudentDao {

    public StudentDaoImpl(){
        setType(Student.class);
    }

}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.souhaieb.education.cursus" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"></tx:annotation-driven>


    <task:annotation-driven></task:annotation-driven>
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <!-- <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/> -->

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:persistence-mysql.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.pass}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.souhaieb.education.cursus.entities.Student</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.souhaieb.education</groupId>
    <artifactId>cursus</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>cursus</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <org.springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies begin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mockito -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jax WS Spring Integration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SLF4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log Back -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons DBCP dependency (for database connection pooling) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL Connector Java dependency (JDBC driver for MySQL) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.31</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate dependencies begin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
            <!--<exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging-processor</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>antlr</groupId>
                    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>Cursus</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

MaintTest.java:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/applicationContext.xml"})

    public class MainTest{

        private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainTest.class);

        @Autowired
        StudentDao studentDao;

        @Test
        public void testStudent(){
            Student student = new Student();
            student.setStudentId(1L);
            student.setCin("05454445");
            student.setFirstName("student1");
            student.setLastName("student1");
            student.setAge(27);
            Long id = studentDao.create(student);
            logger.info("Student ID = "+id);
        }

    }
```