# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dao, autowired

I was not able to resolve my problem with other similar posts. I'm trying to use Hibernate with Spring Boot. Other projects with this kind of configuration are working fine. This one doesn't. Maybe one of you know how to fix this.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=sessionFactory)}

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'priceDaoHibernateImpl' defined in file [D:\Sonstiges\Entwicklung\Projekte\gatrinWS\target\classes\de\xxx\gatrinws\persistence\PriceDaoHibernateImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=sessionFactory)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=sessionFactory)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
at de.xxx.gatrinws.Application.main(Application.java:10)
... 6 more Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=sessionFactory)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
... 25 more
```

This is my configuration

```
<context:component-scan base-package="de.xxx.gatrinws"/>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:global.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="${"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${c3p0.acquireIncrement}"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${c3p0.minPoolSize}"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${c3p0.maxPoolSize}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref local="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_first_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="maxwait">10000</prop>
            <prop key="maxidle">25</prop>
            <prop key="minidle">5</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <array>
            <value>de.xxx.gatrinws</value>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
```

And here is my Dao where autowiring of the sessionFactory seems not to work:
(Class file is located at: de.xxx.gatrinws.service so component scan should work, shouldn't it?)

```
@Repository 
@Transactional
public class PriceDaoHibernateImpl implements PriceDao {

private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
public PriceDaoHibernateImpl(@Qualifier(value = "sessionFactory") SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@Override
public Product findProduct(String ean) {
   return null; // to be added
}
```

}

Does anyone know how to solve this? Service autowiring works like a charm. It seems anything is wrong with the sessionFactory configuration. But: This is how it works for other projects for me.

Thanks in advance!

(In case you're wondering: I x'ed the package base name)

**EDIT:**

It "seems" that the applicationContext.xml (Spring Config) is copied to /target/ while running and some properties cannot be resolved. Do I need to add the target folder anywhere that the properties can be resolved properly?
[see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyjBQ.png)

The no-copied configuration can resolve all properties without any problem.

Comment: Have you tried @Autowired when declaring SessionFactory?

Comment: Yes. already tried. No difference.

Comment: Can you try placing your applicationContext.xml in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF ? That should be the default location for it

Comment: Spring Boot provides auto configurations for hibernate. Do you have any compelling reasons for not using it? With those auto configurations you won't need that xml configuration altogether.

Comment: Post more details about your application, especially `Application` class. Did you try to import the xml config by using `@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")` on `Application` class?

Comment: Thanks to Ali I got it working by using the default configuration just with my connection settings.

Answer (score -3):

Did you try to with autowired annotation?? like below :

```
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Comment: Yep, already tried to add it to the member. Both usually should work but that does not fix the problem :(

Comment: I don't have much idea but you can also try with @Autowired (required=false)

Comment: you can cross verify with the below post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288716/could-not-autowire-dao-no-qualifying-bean-of-type-found-for-dependency?rq=1